# htaccess rewrite rules old.com/folder > new.com, w/ existing htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Quite lost.
I am trying to rewrite the URLs of an old site (old.com/folder) 
to an updated version of the site (new.com) using .htaccess,

where old.com/folder should become new.com

---

The forums indicate that .htaccess would be written in this manner for a standard URL change

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the current .htaccess file has the following rewrite to clean up the URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) /folder/index.php
```

---

What should the .htaccess file look like in order to maintain the re-written structure (sans index.php) & redirect to the new site?

Ex. 
old.com/folder/a/a    >>>>>    new.com/a/a

Answer (score 0):

Your combined .htaccess should be like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ http://www.new.com/$1 [R=302,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]

RewriteRule . /folder/index.php [L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: I changed out the .htaccess file and uploaded it; the redirect is still not working and the old URL doesn't budge.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and restart the browser. Also tell me what URL didn't work. Also make sure above code is in DOCUMENT_ROOT and folder I assume is `DOCUMENT_ROOT/folder`

Comment: So the .htaccess file should be under old.com rather than under old.com/folder ?

(old.com & new.com are stand ins for the actual websites)

Comment: Yes above answer assumes that `.htaccess` will be directly under `old.com/`'s DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the right place. Cleared cache & restarted the browsers I am on, and nothing has changed.

Comment: I really don't want to post the actual URL on here. I have no clue how I would revise the code specifically for my website...

Comment: I will just use redirects (Redirectmatch 302 /a/a/ http://new.com/a/a/) for each url in the .htaccess of the parent domain folder. Laborious, but I suppose it beats working around code I can't quite navigate or revise.

Thanks for all your help. If anyone else can suggest something, by all means, please do.